# Processing.js mouseX and mouseY not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, processing, processing.js

I published a simple processing sketch to my website using processing.js but when I opened it on my iPhone and iPad it didn't work at all. I found a bit of javacript to make it work and it helped, but still mouseX gets the position of the finger in relation to the whole page and not to the canvas area, so it doesn't quite get the position right. What can I do?

The code is live here: http://mqvlm.github.io/blog/rect.html

Here's the javascript i'm using:

```
<canvas ontouchstart="touchStart(event);"
ontouchmove="touchMove(event);"
ontouchend="touchEnd(event);"
ontouchcancel="touchCancel(event);"
id="sketch" width="300" height="300" data-processing-sources="/code/rect.pde"> </canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">

var processingInstance;


function setProcessingMouse(event){
  if (!processingInstance) {  
    processingInstance = Processing.getInstanceById('sketch');  
    }  

  var x = event.touches[0].pageX;
  var y = event.touches[0].pageY;

  processingInstance.mouseX = x;
  processingInstance.mouseY = y;
};

function touchStart(event) {
event.preventDefault();
setProcessingMouse(event);
processingInstance.mousePressed();
};

function touchMove(event) {
event.preventDefault();
setProcessingMouse(event);
processingInstance.mouseDragged();
};

function touchEnd(event) {
event.preventDefault();
setProcessingMouse(event);
processingInstance.mouseReleased();
};

function touchCancel(event) {
event.preventDefault();
setProcessingMouse(event);
processingInstance.mouseReleased();
};

</script>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say it didn't work at all? Can you post a minimal example that just uses Processing code instead of that extra JavaScript code (which shouldn't be necessary)?

Comment: What I meant to sat is that mouseX and mouseY don't work on mobile at all, here, I posted the minimal example without the javascript you suggested, try it on your mobile: http://mqvlm.github.io/prueba.html

Comment: Can you post the code for that minimal example in your question?

Comment: Also, when I run that on my phone, it seems to work okay. Except the sketch shows up twice for some reason.

Comment: Are you running it on Android? I'm running it on safari  iOS 7.2.1. The piece of code I used for the minimal example is just the regular <canvas id="sketch" width="300" height="300" data-processing-sources="/code/rect.pde"> </canvas>

Comment: Yeah, Galaxy Nexus running Android Jelly Bean. I'm asking to see the code for rect.pde, although it sounds like a problem with iOS, not Processing.

Comment: Yes, the processing code is extremely basic, just the regular ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,75,75); I think it's a problem with scrolling on safari for iOS, the touch event gets confused with the scrolling effects and that messes up the mouseX and mouseY recognition. That's why I used the javascript for touchEvents I found somewhere, but the problem with that is it takes the edge of the page as coordinate 0,0 and not the edge of the canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `pageX` and `pageY`, you should use `screenX` and `screenY` to get the position relative to the users screen:

```
var x = event.touches[0].screenX;
var y = event.touches[0].screenY;
```

Or if you want the position relative to the viewport, you can use `clientX` and `clientY`:

```
var x = event.touches[0].clientX;
var y = event.touches[0].clientY;
```

You can check the full list of properties and more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch)

Comment: I used screenX and screenY and it didn't work either. The thing is, what I meant to say earlier, is that on mobile the processing sketch takes the coordinates of the touch event relative to the coordinate 0,0 of the whole page instead of the 0,0 of the canvas, and that's the error. That's why the finger doesn't match the ellipse on mobile! That's what I'd like to get right.

Comment: couldn't find the ideal answer anywhere but using clientX and clientY was the best solution, thanks!

Comment: no problem. Glad to help and I hope you manage to get things to work the way you need them to work :)